# UIImagepicker navigates to superview not to the subview containing UIimagpicker

Tags: ios, objective-c

On ViewControllerA I have added few UIviews and a ViewControllerB's view as asubview. ViewControllerB has imagepicker. After picking image it navigates to ViewControllerA. how can it return to ViewControllerB without disturbing other Views?

```
-(void)changeImage:(id)sender {UIImagePickerController *picker=[[UIImagePickerController alloc]init]; 
    picker.delegate=self; 
    picker.allowsEditing=YES;
    picker.sourceType=UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera; 
    [self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:NULL];     
}
```

Comment: Did you use this code?
`[vcA addChildViewController:vcB];`

when you add vcB as subview of vcA?

Comment: No its like- I have UIview called viewcontent in VCA . I have written in VCA- [viewcontent addsubview:VCB.view]

Comment: Please provide code...

Comment: As I said in I have UIview called viewcontent in VCA . I have written in VCA- [viewcontent addsubview:VCB.view]
 In VCB

Comment: -(void)changeImage:(id)sender
{UIImagePickerController *picker=[[UIImagePickerController alloc]init];
        picker.delegate=self;
        picker.allowsEditing=YES;
        picker.sourceType=UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
        [self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:NULL];
}

Comment: -(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary<NSString *,id> *)info{
    UIImage *chosenImage=info[UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];
    img1.image=chosenImage;
 UIImage* image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];*/
    [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
}

Comment: please mention that where did you add subview and how you are adding as subview

Comment: in VCA - IB I have created UIView called viewContent. created instance of VCB- vcb then added subview as in VCA -[self.view addsubview:vcb]; 
in VCB IB have created uiimageview which actually picks the Image.So the VCB actually serves UIImagepickerDelegate. 
hope I am clear enough.

Answer (score 1):

Add your viewController B to viewController A. In VC A:

Swift 3:

```
instanceOfVCB.willMove(toParentViewController: self)
addChildViewController(instanceOfVCB)
view.addSubview(instanceOfVCB.view)
// add desired contraints to instanceOfVCB.view
instanceOfVCB.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
```

Obj-C:

```
[instanceOfVCB willMoveToParentViewController: self];
[self addChildViewController: instanceOfVCB];
[self.view addSubview: instanceOfVCB.view];
// add desired contraints to instanceOfVCB.view;
[instanceOfVCB didMoveToParentViewController: self];
```

Comment: i think she's asking about objective c

Comment: @zombie: Dropped in some brackets.

Comment: Thanks but I have to add this code in VCA while adding subview isnt it!. and UIimagepicker I am calling from VCB will it solve the issue??

Comment: I did not understand your comment "I have to add this code in VCA while adding subview isnt it!". Does not work for you?

Comment: Please update your question to describe "After picking image it navigates to ViewControllerA" more detailed. Sorry, shallowThought -> slow brain.